# Redirect from view to different view in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem transfering data from one view to another via the controler actions. 
I the first view is a grid.mvc-Grid displayed. By select on row of the grid I get the ID for that object.
by transfering this to an action in the controler I try to filter the data. That works fine.

Here is the filter:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PersonenById(int id)
{
    var personen = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    //Getting the data here :-)

    foreach (DataRow r in access.Rows)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        //do some stuff 
        personen.Add(p);
    }

    //return PartialView("Personen", personen); //does not work
    TempData["personen"] = personen;
    return RedirectToAction("Personen"); // redirect to another view
}
```

In method II the view is filled:

```
public ActionResult Personen()
{
    var persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    if (TempData["Persons"] == null)
    {

     }
  return View(persons); //Works perfect
}   
else
{
    persons = (ObservableCollection<Person>) TempData["Persons"];
    return View(persons);//does not redirect to that View
}
```

}

(Sorry for the strange formating. :-))

Is there any different way to send data from a view to another?
I tried: 
return partial;
return View("Persons",persons);
 and a lot other stuff.

Comment: "Sorry for the strange formating" - do not apologise, just format it correctly, because code is almost unreadable.

Comment: Your line endings aren't correct.

Comment: Formatted part of it but the second code block has too many braces so unsure what code is supposed to be. Also TempData["Persons"] != TempData["personen"]

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect in a .cshtml view.

Eg:

```
    Context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    Context.Response.Redirect(
        $"{Context.Request.PathBase}/Error/403", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Personen", model);
```

Also, the "Personen" action should have the model as an argument, like this:

```
public ActionResult Personen(Person model) ...
```

LE: I have also noticed you have tried to send the data through the TempData object. Make sure the indexed object's name is the same (e.g. `TempData["person"]` everywhere)

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but TempData["person"] is just a error caused by copy'n'paste.
When I set a breakpoint to the targetview, the breakpoint will be reached in the view. But the view is not displayed.

Comment: You mean the `.cshtml` or `.aspx` view? There you must have the same `ObservableCollection<Person>` model specified, if yes.

Comment: Hi Andrei.
Yes, its a .cshtml-View. The ObservableCollection<Person> is identical ( imo). Otherwise the Grid in the view wouldn'd get any data, or? What not happens is the redirect to the different view in browser. The view is not displayed.

Comment: You can't do a redirect with a payload. Redirects cause the client's browser to issue a GET request for the new URL. As a result, you can only pass data via a query string, since that's all the GET method supports. While you *could* attempt to break down your class into query string parameters, this would be clunky. If you need to work with the same object, it's best to just pass along the id with the new URL and look it up again with that.